# Analysing ORACLE EXPLAIN PLAN

Tags: performance, oracle, query-optimization, explain, sql-execution-plan

Browser is getting hanged while generating  jasper report[PDF format] which runs a query
whose explain plan is given below.

Please help to anlyse the query, is this query taking too much time?
We also noticed stuck thread while generating this report.

[image: Explain Plan of the report query]

Comment: "is this query taking too much time?" - You're the only one that can answer that question.

Comment: We can't analyse the query without seeing it (and the table scripts)... however, from the explain plan you do have a Cartesian join. Is this intended?

Comment: @Ollie the problem is with report generation. we are not sure whether query is taking too much time or report is taking time to download. So i have posted the explain plan.

Comment: @AvinashKP, I really wasn't being flippant. Not knowing your database structure, SQL query, what you are trying to achieve and data volumes as well as a host of other factors possibly including how much time you are prepared to tolerate for your report to run, there isn't a lot anyone on here can do to help. You've simply not given us enough information yet. To test the query time, extract the SQL from the DB and run it seperately, that'll tell you how long the query takes, the rest is the report (give or take a little).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

is The EXPLAIN PLAN is the optimizer's *informed guess* at how your query will run, including how  long it will take.  The opt imizer bases this guess on many things, including what statistics it has regarding data volumes and system characteristics.

These gueses are usually pretty good, especially in the later versions of Oracle.  But they can still be out, especially if your statistics are stale, if your data distribution is skewed or because of ambient system conditions.

In your particular case the optimizer is guessing that your query returns one row: does that sound right?  If not your statistics are inaccurate and need refreshing.

As for time, the optimizer is guessing that your query will take 45 seconds to run.  Is that too long?  Only you can tell?

Bear in mind that database tuning is a complex science.  It requires lots of detailed information.  People forge entire careers by tuning slow-running queries.  Tuning is even more complicated in web applications because there are so many points where the architecture or bad coding can introduce bottlenecks.  It is very difficult to get a profile of the performance of the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with APC. i also got surprised looking at expected time (45 sec). To add, explain plan is an 'expected plan' by CBO. Sometime, 'Actual' vs 'Expected' differs after real execution.

So, its better to check actual plan as well. Following can be used get the actual plan:

1) Using dbms_xplan

```
explain plan for <SELECT ...>
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);            --estimated plan
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display_cursor);     --actual plan
```

2) Trigger '10046 trace' and TKPROF

```
alter session set tracefile_identifier = 'something-unique'
alter session set sql_trace = true;
alter session set events '10046 trace name context forever, level 8';
```